What analysis is best with a binary independent variable that is very skewed?
I have a binary independent variable (1 = event occurs, 0 = no event occurs) and a continuous moderating variable. My dependent variables are continuous. I want to test if engaging in a particular event predicts higher scores on psychological outcomes than when one does not engage in a particular event, and I also want to test for moderation effects. My sample size is between 350-450 observations (keeping details vague for anonymity purposes).
The number of 1s in my independent variable is very low (7% of observations = 1, 93% = 0). I read that skewness of an independent variable isn't a big concern, but this seems like a pretty big issue -- is it? Can I run a linear regression analysis regardless of this skew, or is another test more suitable in this case? A MANOVA comes to mind, but I'm not certain of the pros/cons between that and regression in this case or if I'd have to convert my continuous moderator to a binary (high/low) variable for MANOVA. TIA!

Welcome to Cross Validated!  I have the feeling that a regression for each dependent variable will serve you better than a MANOVA or MANCOVA covering all at once.  MAN(C)OVA (like canonical correlation, which you may have considered as well) tends to provide answers to murkier, more abstract questions that ultimately are of less interest to most audiences.  Also, depending on the software you use, structuring your analysis as regression may give you more diagnostic and graphical options.

This is not an issue at all and your analysis should not change based on the distribution of this variable. A regression model with event, your moderator, and their interaction would be sufficient. I would not recommend binning your moderator, but it would be a good idea to allow to flexibly relate to your outcome (e.g., using splines).
The only effect of having an imbalanced predictor is that the mean outcome for those in the smaller group will be predicted with far less accuracy than that for those in the larger group. The same is true of the simple slope in the moderation analysis, should you choose to compute that. But that is a fact of the matter, not something can be fixed by analysis.

A corollary to the second paragraph is that, if you find yourself with the resources to acquire more data, you would get more out of gathering more minority-category observations than majority-category observations.
